# Punctuation for "или ... или"

Tags: пунктуация

What would be the right punctuation in "Он или притворяется, или вообще ничего не понимает"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rosenthal, *Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию*, §87:

> Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами
>
> Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством повторяющихся союзов *и... и, да... да, ни... ни, или... или, ли... ли, либо... либо, то... то* и др., например:
>
> - *Темнота раннего зимнего утра скрывала и площадку на берегу, и полотняный поселок из палаток, и самих людей (Ажаев);*
> - *Ни справа, ни слева, ни на воде, ни на берегу никого не было (Гайдар);*
> - *С чужими я либо робел, либо важничал (Горький);*
> - *Лицо радиста то хмурилось, то улыбалось (Горбатов):*
> - *Наверху за потолком кто-то не то стонет, не то смеется (Чехов).*

Your punctuation is right.

Answer (score 4):

That's already the right punctuation

```
Он или притворяется, или вообще ничего не понимает.
```

Once you have *или ... или*, you need a comma in front of the latter *или*.

Comment: True, and this holds even for more complex situations: *Он или однотонный красный или белый, или вообще в горошек*.